# Manhwa where the female lead gets cheated on by her fiance, so she goes back in time and has a contract relationship with his brother

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, magic

The female lead goes back in time, and proposes a contract relationship with the older brother of her ex-fiance. The older brother is in a wheelchair, because his legs don't work. But he is pretending, he can walk, and he is plotting revenge against his brother. There was a scene where the FL and ML put on a show by pretending to use magic healing water on his ankles, and it heals his legs, but he could always use his legs. The female lead also uses strong magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[I Wasn't the Cinderella](https://m.tapas.io/series/i-wasnt-the-cinderella/info)*.

> How could Terryl’s boyfriend leave her simply because of her low status? After her humiliating breakup, a mysterious man tells Terryl the shocking truth about her identity—she’s the daughter of a powerful duke! With her advanced standing in society and newfound powers, Terryl plans revenge against her pitiful ex-boyfriend and contemplates marrying his brother, Cesio. This way, he’ll never get the title of marquis! But what will Terryl do when she discovers Cesio’s dark secret? Will she get her happily ever after, or is that just a fairytale?

The synopsis covers the breakup and the focus on revenge against her ex-fiance. This is not a time travel story; instead, after discovering she's the daughter of a duke, she simply disappears from the public eye for a few years.

She plans to marry her ex-fiance's disabled, mute brother:

[image: Description of the disabled brother]     [image: Contract marriage]

As mentioned in the question, he is faking it. The two brothers do not have the same mother, and the disabled brother's stepmother is paranoid that he wants to take the inheritance away from her son.

And it includes the fake water ceremony.

[image: prelude to fake water ceremony]